# How to create a layout for use with pisa (xhtml2pdf)?

Tags: python, css, pdf, pisa, xhtml2pdf

I'm creating PDFs using pisa. The layouts I'm trying to convert to PDF have some absolute positioning which seems to be ignored by pisa. I could work around this limitation by using tables for layout. Are there any alternatives to this?

Comment: Use tables. It's ok for pisa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do absolute positioning is to use the xhtml2pdf specific @frame blocks. See the [documentation](https://github.com/chrisglass/xhtml2pdf/blob/master/doc/pisa-en.html) for details.